# Add mixin with ko.computed to knockout viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mixins

After reading this article: [A fresh look at javascript mixins](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) I wanted to move some common knockout computed functions to a mixin and mix that into each viewmodel that needs the functionality.

**First the mixin function**

```
var asActor = function() {
    this.nrOfEmployees = ko.computed(function () {
        if (this.employees())
            return this.employees().length;
        return 0;
    }, this).extend({ throttle: 20 });
    this.nrOfAddresses = ko.computed(function () {
        if (this.addresses())
            return this.addresses().length;
        return 0;
    }, this).extend({ throttle: 20 })
};
```

**Then the call to mix the mixin into the target objects prototype**

```
asActor.call(SenderActor.prototype);
asActor.call(ReceiverActor.prototype);
```

My problem seems to be that **this** (or **self** which is set to **this** inside the viewmodel) points to the windows object and not the viewmodel. Any ideas? Javascript mixins is new to me so I'm probably missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asActor.call(SenderActor.prototype);` does the following -

1. it calls `asActor` and passes `SenderActor.protototype` object as `this`
2. `this.nrOfEmployees = ko.computed(...)` creates a ko.computed inside `SenderActor.protototype`
3. it evaluates the computed in same context `this` still points to `SenderActor.protototype`

Depending on whether you do or do not have `employees` in your `SenderActor.protototype` or it's chain of prototypes this code will or will not produce errors.

Now **I am assuming** this behaviour is not what you were aming at.

Try running `asActor.call(this);` inside SenderActor constructor.

Comment: Great answer which led me to my solution. Since I don't have access to change the constructor (it is generated on the fly from the server) I needed to add these methods another way. See my answer for details.

Comment: I will reward you the answer since it helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you create new object by a function, say new asActor(), there will be a default value to return for you - the magic "this". You must add a return statement when you just run a function.

I've tested your code, it has no problems but there no return value from running asActor.

```
var asActor = function() {
  this.nrOfEmployees = ko.computed(function () {
      if (this.employees())
        return this.employees().length;
    return 0;
  }, this).extend({ throttle: 20 });
  this.nrOfAddresses = ko.computed(function () {
    if (this.addresses())
        return this.addresses().length;
    return 0;
  }, this).extend({ throttle: 20 })

  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As Olga said, creating a computed on the prototype itself was not really my intention. The solution I chose was to use a Base class:

```
var Base = function () {
    var extenders = [];

    this.extend = function (extender) {
        extenders.push(extender);
    };

    this.init = function () {
        var self = this; // capture the class that inherits off of the 'Base' class

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(extenders, function (extender) {

            // call each extender with the correct context to ensure all
            // inheriting classes have the same functionality added by the extender
            extender.call(self);
        });
    };
};
```

In the generation code I added **this.Init() call in all viewmodel constructors**.

Finally I called the .extend function on each viewmodel to have these functions mixed in:

```
SenderActor.prototype.extend(asActor);
ReceiverActor.prototype.extend(asActor);
```

Comment: Neat solution. For the sake of completness do add code for inhereting Base. `Base.call(Cat.prototype)` worked for me.

Comment: Good point, I forgot that... To inherit Base I add `SenderActor.prototype = new Base();` after defining the SenderActor constructor.